# How can I repair power armor?

Tags: fallout-4

I have a set of badly damaged power armor that I got early in the game, but I have no idea how to actually repair it. There isn't an option in the inventory for it.

How exactly can I repair the pieces of power armor that I have?

Comment: [Notes on repairing a companion's armor here.](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/243653/108003)

Answer (score 15):

You need to find a [Power Armor Station](http://gamesnosh.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/fallout-4-power-armor-customization.png). If you exit your power armor in front of this station, or interact with the station while wearing power armor, then using the station will give you the option to modify and repair the constituent pieces of the armor.

Sanctuary has a Power Armor Station, as well as the Red Rocket station you reach early in the game.

Comment: just as an added tip, you can also attach it to the station while wearing the power armor by trying to interact with it (PC: 'e').  you'll automatically get out of the suit at that point.  After that you need to interact with the station itself (not the armor) to do repairs and other upgrades.

Comment: You might want to add a bit on how to acutally use the Power Armor Station, I was pretty confused at the beginning about this.

Comment: @MadScientist By which part of it? Once you have a suit sitting there and you use the station itself, all of the options are laid out on the UI. I'm not sure what to add here.

Comment: My option to repair broken armor is greyed out (0/125 hp armor). Any idea why?

Comment: @AffluentOwl Only thing I can think of is that it requires components (typically steel). If you don't have enough steel on you, or enough junk in a linked workshop which can be broken down into steel, that could explain it.

Comment: That was the problem. I used a power station in a different settlement than my main, so there were no resources for use there.